# How to place order through rest API magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, api, sales-order, rest-api, guest-checkout

I want to place an order as a guest user through rest API in Magento 1.Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: In default magento not implemented. Please see here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html

Comment: @Abdul default order rest api document post method is not available.

Comment: Not implemented yet.

Comment: is there any way to implement that ?

Comment: Yes it is possible but take lot time :D